# Symfony, Twig: Persistent route parameters

Tags: parameters, routes, twig, slug, symfony

I am making an app in Symfony3. Part of the application is sectioned by dynamic subdomains --- the subdomain is represented by a slug.

```
subdomains:
     host: "{slug}.{domain}"
     default:
           slug: example
     ...
```

When running on local example of such route would be e.g. `http://a.localhost`

When I create a link in Twig, either using `{{ url('route') }}` or `{{ path('route') }}`, the subdomain is always *forgotten*, and slug in paramenter falls to default *example*, always making routes `http://example.localhost`.

**Is there a way to implicitly copy the parameters, or mark some parameters persistent, so that I do not have to make all the links include the slug** like this `{{ url('route', {'slug' : slug}) }}`, in order to stay on the subdomain?

Thank you

Comment: What does the profiler say about "Route parameters" on the "Routing" panel? (/app_dev.php/_profiler/latest?panel=router)

Comment: @TobiasXy the slug parameter is listed as expected in "Routing parameters" with *_locale* and *domain* parameters. No additional information is provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a [TwigExtension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) for the purpose of generating links within the subdomain.

I would prefer if it were possible to make some parameters "persistent" as I mentioned in the question. Those would be implicitly carried across relative paths, but possibly nulled with explicit parameter choice. If this is not possible, I consider this better option than adding the parameter manually and best option so far.

**Extension class**

```
/**
 * ApplicationExtension constructor.
 *
 * @param Router $router
 * @param RequestStack $requestStack
 */
public function __construct(Router $router, RequestStack $requestStack)
{
    $this->router = $router;
    $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
}

public function getFunctions()
{
    return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('domainPath', [
                    $this,
                    'domainPath'
            ]),
    ];
}

public function domainPath($route_name, $params = [])
{
    if (!array_key_exists('slug', $params)) {
        $params['slug'] = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->attributes->get('slug');
    }
    return $this->router->generate($route_name, $params);
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'application_extension';
}
```

**Register service** (DI and Tag)

```
application.twig.application_extension:
        class: ApplicationBundle\Twig\ApplicationExtension
        arguments: ["@router", "@request_stack"]
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

**Use in template**

```
{{ domainPath('route_name') }}
```